# Show author name and not author id under comments

Tags: php, cakephp-2.2

In my application I have 2 controllers, one for articles (`Articles`) and one for article comments (`Article_Comments`). Their tables look like this:

```
Articles
id, author_id, type_id, body, created, modified

Article_Comments
id, article_id, author_id, body, created, modified
```

Now on the view of the article, I show the comments as well. But the comments doesn't show the name of the author of that comment. It only shows the `author_id`.

How can I change it so it shows the name and not the id?

**EDIT 1**

This is the code for the Articles view: (the bit where the comments are shown)

```
<?php if (!empty($article['articleComment'])):
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($article['articleComment'] as $articleComment): ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                Response By: <?php echo $articleComment['author_id']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                On: <?php echo $articleComment['created']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><?php echo $articleComment['comment']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Where is the code of the view that parses the author id?

Comment: Hi Sven, I added the Articles view. Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: If the article view displays the author name, can the same code be applied for the comment?

Comment: You obviously need an `Author` model (which I suppose you already have) and get it linked with `Article_Comments`. And you'll need to make use of aliases since you can have authors both two items (article and comments).

Comment: Hi @ÁlvaroG.Vicario, I have already linked `Author` to `Article_Comments`. `Article_Comments` is defined in the `Author` model under `$hasMany`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have already linked `Author` to `Article_Comments`. `Article_Comment`s is
>   defined in the `Author` model under `$hasMany`.

That relationship is required to retrieve comments from the `Author` model but you need to create the opposite relationship because you're fetching data from `Article_Comments`. Something like this:

```
class Article_Comments extends AppModel{
    public $belongsTo = 'Author';
}
```

Comment: That's already there. I have no idea why it's not working then.

Comment: Have you changed the `$recursive` property somewhere, e.g. in `AppModel`?

Comment: @DarkRanger - Can you test whether setting it explicitly (e.g. to `3`) changes something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a join of Article_Comments with author's table and put this field in the select statment to get the name of the autor.